# Class decorator object has no attribute __name__

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-decorators

I have written a decorator class which goes like this:

```py
import functools

class ViewCounter(object):
    def __init__(self,user_slug=None):
        self.user_slug = user_slug

    def __call__(self, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            return func(*args,**kwargs)
        return wrapped_func
```

I have applied this to one of my class based views with Django's `method_decorator`, like this:

```py
class ProjectPage(DetailView):
    template_name = 'account/profile-page-latest.html'
    model = User
    context_object_name = 'user_obj'

    @method_decorator(ViewCounter) 
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProjectPage, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

I get this error in my console:

```
AttributeError: 'ViewCounter' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Comment: What is `method_decorator`? If it's from [this module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/method_decorator/0.1.3), the very brief docs suggest that you're supposed to inherit from it, rather than call it (but I don't have any first hand experience with it myself).

Comment: from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator .. its from here .. @Blckknght

Answer (score 0):

I believe using `@method_decorator(ViewCounter())` should solve the problem. `ViewCounter` isn't a function decorator, it's a class whose instances are function decorators.